# Inline link tag and another class have ico :after

Tags: html, css

I want the new icon to be in line with the PDF icon in item `li` have class "new" so icon new will after icon PDF without modifying the HTML code structure 
and I wanna keep text-indent. I tried to edit the display but did not get it.

```css
ul, li {
      list-style: none;
}
.linkList > li + li {
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}
.txtLinkDC, .pdfLink, .wordLink, .excelLink, .zipLink {
    text-indent: -20px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 20px;
    word-break: break-all;
}
.txtLinkDC:before, .pdfLink:before, .wordLink:before, .excelLink:before, .zipLink:before {
    content: url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/windows-8/16/Very-Basic-Document-icon.png);
    margin-right: 6px;
}
.pdfLink:after {
    content: url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/treetog/file-type/16/pdf-icon.png);
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.new:after {
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    content: " ";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 12px;
    background: url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/colorful-long-shadow/16/New-icon.png);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<ul class="linkList">
<li><a href="#" target="_blank" class="pdfLink">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</a></li>
<li><a href="#" target="_blank" class="wordLink">bcbbbbbbbbbb</a></li>
<li><a href="#" target="_blank" class="excelLink">cccccccccccccc</a></li>
<li><a href="#" target="_blank" class="pdfLink">dddddddddddđ</a></li>
<li class="new"><a href="#" target="_blank" class="pdfLink">eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</a></li>
<li class="txt-note text-indent comments-mark">ffffffffffffffffffffffff</li>
</ul>
```

[Link code](https://jsfiddle.net/37wf6zqa/15/)

Comment: You want the icons side by side within the same line? Please clarify the question.

Comment: Yah, sorry :), i want icons side by side.

Comment: I'm totally confused.  What's with the HTML code?  I don't see any icons ....

Answer (score 0):

Try adding using a span tag inside the a tag. Use this on the rest of your lines. Thumb up if it helps.

```css
/*
Then replace this css in yours so it shows side by side
.pdfLink:before {
    content: url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/treetog/file-type/16/pdf-icon.png);
    margin-left: 10px;
}

*/
```

```html
<li><a href="#" target="_blank" class="pdfLink"><span class="wordLink"></span>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</a></li>

<!-- I added a span with the class wordLink -->
```

Comment: Sorry, there is a bit of confusion here .. I mean here is where the class new and the new icon will be in line with the pdf icon. So icon new will after icon pdf

Answer (score 0):

Is the code below ok for you:

```css
ul, li {
      list-style: none;
}
.linkList > li + li {
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}
.txtLinkDC, .pdfLink, .wordLink, .excelLink, .zipLink {
    text-indent: -20px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    word-break: break-all;
}
.txtLinkDCLi:before, .pdfLinkLi:before, .wordLinkLi:before, .excelLinkLi:before, .zipLinkLi:before {
    content: url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/windows-8/16/Very-Basic-Document-icon.png);
    margin-right: 0px;
}
.pdfLink:after {
    content: url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/treetog/file-type/16/pdf-icon.png);
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.new:after {
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    content: " ";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 12px;
    background: url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/colorful-long-shadow/16/New-icon.png);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<ul class="linkList">
<li class="pdfLinkLi"><a href="#" target="_blank" class="pdfLink">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</a></li>
<li class="wordLinkLi"><a href="#" target="_blank" class="wordLink">bcbbbbbbbbbb</a></li>
<li class="excelLinkLi"><a href="#" target="_blank" class="excelLink">cccccccccccccc</a></li>
<li class="pdfLinkLi"><a href="#" target="_blank" class="pdfLink">dddddddddddđ</a></li>
<li class="pdfLinkLi">
<a href="#" target="_blank" class="pdfLink">eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</a><span class="new"></span></li>
<li class="txt-note text-indent comments-mark">ffffffffffffffffffffffff</li>
</ul>
```